# How to parse items from JSON string in Java

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have this code and I tried to getting items from this JSON string but it failed.

I'm parsing the Json string from remote host.

```
package selectDB;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.sql.*;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import org.json.simple.*;

public class selectDB
 {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException
  {
      String s = "";
      URL u = new URL("http://192.168.3.1/android/select.php");
      URLConnection c = u.openConnection();
      InputStream r = c.getInputStream();
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(r));
      for(String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;)
          {
            s+=line;
          }
      System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

the result is

```
{"result" : "true" , "messages" : [{"id":"866343023633578","latitute":"27","longitude":"31","number_phone":"01113171374"},{"id":"352168066354050","latitute":"27","longitude":"31","number_phone":"202222"},{"id":"50","latitute":"50","longitude":"100","number_phone":"50"},{"id":"110","latitute":"50","longitude":"50","number_phone":"110"},{"id":"120","latitute":"27","longitude":"31","number_phone":"120"},{"id":"130","latitute":"28","longitude":"29","number_phone":"120"},{"id":"140","latitute":"30","longitude":"40","number_phone":"140"},{"id":"800","latitute":"60","longitude":"30","number_phone":"800"},{"id":"353629054230064","latitute":"70","longitude":"80","number_phone":"120"}]}
```

Please help!

Comment: question not very clear

Answer (score 1):

U can use the JsonReader class.

```
try (JsonReader in = Json.createReader(r)) {

      JsonObject jsonObject= in.readObject();
      YourObject obj = new YourObject();
      obj.setSomething(jsonObject.getString("something", null));

      // "something" is the key in the json file, null is the default
      // when "something" was not found      

} catch (JsonException | ClassCastException ex) {
      throw new BadRequestException("Invalid Json Input");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Google Library GSON as well, it is easy to use and self explaining.

https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

> Gson Goals
>
> Provide simple toJson() and fromJson() methods to convert Java objects to JSON and vice-versa
>       Allow pre-existing unmodifiable objects to be converted to and from JSON
>       Extensive support of Java Generics
>       Allow custom representations for objects
>       Support arbitrarily complex objects (with deep inheritance hierarchies and extensive use of generic types)